# VisualEditor for MediaWiki wiki via node.js on Heroku

Tags: mediawiki, heroku, node-js

For small non-WMF wikis on economical shared hosting it might be possible to get [Extension:VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) running without having to upgrade to VPS hosting. That is by installing [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Setup) to run on [Heroku's node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs).

Please some advice on how to go about this and what are the risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an installation walk-through at MediaWiki's [VisualEditor on a shared host](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor_on_a_shared_host) page.